# ASP.NET MVC Client-Side Validation with a JavaScript Loader

Tags: asp.net-mvc, yepnope

Has anyone tried using MVC client-side validation with a JavaScript loader, specifically yepnope.js? I can't get it to work, and I believe it's because it registers the validation code before the necessary JS files have loaded.

I can get it working by loading jQuery, jquery.validation, MicrosoftAjax, and MicrosoftMvcValidation normally (i.e., outside of yepnope), but I wonder if anyone has a better solution. Thanks.

Comment: For default validation in asp.net mvc to work, you need two files, jquery.validation.js and jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js. Are you missing the second one?

Comment: Like I wrote, I can get it working when I load jQuery, jquery.validation, MicrosoftAjax, and MicrosoftMvcValidation outside of yepnope. It just doesn't work when I load those files using yepnope.js.

Answer (score 1):

on the completed event of the YepNope please execute the below script where formName will be the name of your form.

```
  $(formName).removeData("validator");
  $(formName).removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(formName);
```